# Date Picker for Polymer 2.x

Tags: datepicker, polymer-2.x

Is there any Date picker component that supports polymer 2.x?

I have tried the [*Vaadin Date Picker*](https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-date-picker#demos) component of [Vaadin Elements](https://vaadin.com/elements). But it generates errors as it does not support polymer 2.x. See [Issue # 344 – Polymer 2.0 Support](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker/issues/344).

Answer (score 0):

Try setup #2.0-preview version of Vaadin Date Picker